# How to capitalize first letter in this program

Tags: java, string

I've written majority of this. I just can't figure out how to capitalize the first letter of each line. the problem is:

Write a program that checks a text file for several formatting and punctuation matters. The program asks for the names of both an input file and an output file. It then copies all the text from the input file to the output file, but with the following two changes (1) Any string of two or more blank characters is replaced by a single blank; (2) all sentences start with an uppercase letter. All sentences after the first one begin after either a period, a question mark, or an exclamation mark that is followed by one or more whitespace characters.

I've written most of the code. I just need help with the capitalization of the first letter of each sentence. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TextFileProcessor
{
public static void textFile()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inputSent;
    String oldText;
    String newText;


    System.out.print("Enter the name of the file that you want to test: ");
    oldText = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of your output file:");
    newText = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("\n");

    try
    {
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldText));
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(newText));
        inputSent = inputStream.readLine();

        inputSent = inputSent.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
        inputSent = inputSent.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + inputSent.substring(1);

        inputSent = inputSent.replace("?", "?\n").replace("!", "!\n").replace(".", ".\n");
        //Find a way to make the first letter capitalized

        while(inputSent != null)
        {
            outputStream.println(inputSent);
            System.out.println(inputSent);
            inputSent = inputStream.readLine();
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File" + oldText + " could not be located.");
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was an error in file" + oldText);
    }
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class TextFileProcessorDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String inputName;
    String result;
    String sentence;


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Enter the name of your input file: ");
    inputName = keyboard.nextLine();
    File input = new File(inputName);

    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try
    {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(input);
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening the file. Goodbye!" + input);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter a line of text:");
    sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

    outputStream.println(sentence);
    outputStream.close();

    System.out.println("This line was written to:" + " " + input);
    System.out.println("\n");

}
}
```

Comment: You could make an array of 'special characters', that are used only at the end of the sentence, then if you see this character you know that a new sentence is starting. Check the next character (that is not a space), for capitalization.

Comment: You know that Sentences start at the beginning of the input or after a punctuation mark (!, ? or .). So look for the first non-whitespace character after those and capitalize it. You could use regex, `indexOf()` or `split()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is maybe using [WordUtil](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String,%20char...%29) from Apache commons-langs.

You should use the `capitalise` method with the delimiters as parameter.

Comment: That exact line is already contained in the question. Besides that the code implies that there are multiple sentences in the string and the line you posted would only handle the very first.

Comment: @Thomas you are right! I will modify my answer. +1 for yours

Answer (score 1):

Since your code already contains `inputSent = inputSent.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + inputSent.substring(1);` I assume that `inputSent` can contain more than one sentence or might just represent a line of the file with parts of sentences.

Thus I'd suggest you first read the entire file into a string (if it's not too large) and then use `split()` on that string to break it into individual sentences, capitalize the first character and join them again.

Example:

```
String[] sentences = fileContent.split("(?<=[?!.])\\s*");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for( String sentence : sentences) {
  //append the first character as upper case
  result.append( Character.toUpperCase( sentence.charAt(0) ) );
  //add the rest of the sentence
  result.append( sentence.substring(1) );
  //add a newline
  result.append("\n");
}

//I'd not replace the input, but to be consistent with your code
fileContent = result.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
(\S)([^.!?]*[.!?]( |$))
```

[image: regex]

- *Code:*

  ```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String inputSent = "hi! how are you? fine, thanks.";
      inputSent = inputSent.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S)([^.!?]*[.!?]( |$))").matcher(inputSent);
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      while (m.find()) {
          m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase() + m.group(2) + "\n");
      }
      m.appendTail(sb);
      System.out.println(sb);
  }
  ```

  See a [*demo*](https://ideone.com/f7EVrz) online.
- *Output:*

  ```
  Hi! 
  How are you? 
  Fine, thanks.
  ```

Comment: I'd describe the individual parts of the regex for better understanding. Besides that, `[^.!?]*[.!?]` can be simplified pt `.*?[.!?]` using the reluctant quantifier. Additionally using `Matcher` would also just require to find the first character in a sentence since `appendReplacement()` will append the part before the match as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASCII table lower and upper case are just integers that are 32 positions away from each other...

try something like this:

```
String inputSent = .... //where ever it does come from...
System.out.println(inputSent.replace(inputSent.charAt(0), (char) (inputSent.charAt(0) - 32)));
```

or use some kind of APACHE libs like [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html).

Comment: The line `inputSent = inputSent.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + inputSent.substring(1);`is already present in this code and takes other characters than ASCII ones in account. The issue is when there are several sentences in the same line.

Comment: Java's `String`, `char`, and `charAt` are not ASCII; They are [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html)/UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `textFile()` to the below:

```
public static void textFile()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inputSent;
    String oldText;
    String newText;


    System.out.print("Enter the name of the file that you want to test: ");
    oldText = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of your output file:");
    newText = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("\n");

    try
    {
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldText));
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(newText));
        while ((inputSent = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            char[] chars = inputSent.toCharArray();
            chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]);
            inputSent = new String(chars);

            inputSent = inputSent.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
            inputSent = inputSent.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + inputSent.substring(1);

            inputSent = inputSent.replace("?", "?\n").replace("!", "!\n").replace(".", ".\n");
            System.out.println("-> " + inputSent);
            outputStream.println(inputSent);

        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File" + oldText + " could not be located.");
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was an error in file" + oldText);
    }
}
```

1. This will read the text file line by line.
2. Upper the first char
3. Do this in a while loop

The problem with your original textFile() is that it only applies uppercase first char, blank space etc on the very first line it reads.